# Reorder table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I reorder table rows?

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="text-align: center; width: 95%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 2%;"></td>
        <td>Prekės pavadinimas</td>
        <td style="width: 15%;">Kiekis</td>
        <td style="width: 15%;">Kaina</td>
        <td style="width: 15%;">Suma</td>
        <td style="width: 2%;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span><br>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="product"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product" name="product" placeholder="Prekė">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="quantity"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Kiekis">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Kaina">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="total"></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total" name="total" placeholder="Suma" disabled>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color: red;"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$('tr td span:nth-of-type(1)').on('click', function() {
    moveup = $(this).parent();
    moveup.prev().before(moveup);
});

$('tr td span:nth-of-type(2)').on('click', function() {
    movedown = $(this).parent();
    movedown.next().after(movedown);
});
```

And here is how my code now working with jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/zJ8hd/21/

Thanks for help in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic for traversal and amending the DOM isn't quite right. You need to get the parent `tr` element and then insert it before/after the prev/next `tr`, something like this:

```
$('tr td span:nth-of-type(1)').on('click', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr')
    if ($row.index() == 1)
        return;
    $row.insertBefore($row.prev());
});

$('tr td span:nth-of-type(2)').on('click', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr')
    $row.insertAfter($row.next());
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/zJ8hd/24/)

Note I added `foo` and `bar` as default field values in the fiddle only to make the movement more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
moveup =  $(this).parent();
```

Here, `this` refers to the span, so its parent is a `td` not the row. If you want to move the whole row, you should give a look at `.closest()`(1) and then use `.prev()` or `.next()`.

Your are close to the solution, I'll let you work a little ;)

1 -> https://api.jquery.com/closest/